# Error When Using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Tags: mysql, file-io, load, local

**What I Am Trying To Do:**

I am trying to use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`.
I have a csv file on a server I work on that I want to load onto a table in a MySQL database. I have used the following:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/var/www/load_data_test.csv'
INTO TABLE name_age 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

**What My Problem Is:**

My problem is an error code. When I run this in MySQL (HeidiSQL), I am getting the following error message:

> SQL Error (2): File '\var\www\load_data_test.csv' not found (Errcode: 2)

**What I Have Tried:**

I googled this problem and all the links that I clicked on lead me to try the following:

1. Setting the permissions on the file to `Octal: 7777`. I have given Read, Write, and Execute permissions to Owner, Group and Others. This did not work. I was still given the same error message as above.
2. Taking out the `LOCAL` word in the MySQL statement. I Changed the first line of the SQL command to `LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/www/load_data_test.csv'`. This did not work, and produced the following error message:
   `SQL Error (29): File 'var/www/load_data_test.csv' not found (Errcode: 13)`.
3. Switching the owner under the file's properties to `root`. This does not work. When I try to do this, I get the error message `Command 'chown "root" "load_data_test.csv"' failed with return code 1 and error message chown: changing ownership of 'load_data_test.csv': Opertion not permitted.`.

**Possible Constraints**

- My lack of knowledge pertaining to permission levels. I have never really worked with permission levels before.
- My lack of knowledge pertaining to the `LOAD DATA (LOCAL) INFILE` command. I am unfamiliar with this MySQL command, and this is my first time using it.
- I do not have root access on either the Linux or MySQL server.

I am 100% sure that the CSV file I am trying to load onto the database table is on the server, so I am confused as to why it won't even recognize it in the first place. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a quick solution to my own problem. Posting it up just in case anyone who encounters this needs a solution too.

In HeidiSQL, you can upload CSV files through the GUI, and when you do, it gives you the syntax for the file upload (the GUI also uses the `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` command). I was able to get the same CSV file, on my own computer, to upload into the MySQL table on my server using the following syntax:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\Users\\acarella\\Desktop\\load_data_test.csv' 
INTO TABLE `ug_warehouse`.`name_age` 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
IGNORE 1 LINES (`name`, `age`);
```

This is probably my first time answering a question on StackOverflow, so if it is unorthodox to answer your own question then I will avoid doing it in the future.

-Anthony